# PHP Cron-Jobs timeout error

Tags: php, cron

i am using a free domain to host my very humble website that has nothing besides 1 php/html page and 1 php script.
The imagechange.php script is as follows:

```
<?php
unlink("images/show.png");
$images = glob("images/*.png");
copy($images[rand(0,count($images))],"images/show.png");
?>
```

`*each time it runs, it should switch show.png to a different image from the directory.`

When i directly access the page (from URL bar) the script works perfectly. I mean, nothing shows up on the screen but the image does indeed change.

My hierarchy looks like so:
`~/public_html/imagechange.php`

When i used the built-in cronjob options in my free domain it said i set it to each 5 minutes, and it would execute the following command: `php -f /home/a3638901/public_html/imagechange.php`

[image: FTP Folder hierarchy]

I let it run for hours and it wouldn't change a thing. I thought to myself, well, maybe it's just the bad host. 
So i used an  [external service](http://cron-job.org) which allows me to do the same. This time i set it to each 10 minutes, and each time it would plot `Timeout error`.
[image: Error log]
I really have no clue what could be possibly the problem with the script, or the cronjob.

Would appreciate guidance or troubleshooting, thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of trying to delete and copy over an image, why not just return a different source string based on a time calculation? Avoid over-engineering the whole thing.

Comment: @Blake (Not sure if i understood what you are trying to say but.. ) Thats because the `.png` file location needs to be used as a signature at a forum. It has to be a `.png` url for it to work.

Comment: Got to agree with Blake that you're fixing the wrong problem here. But there is no way that it should take 30 seconds to copy a file - and if it were failing it would fail a lot quicker. I suspect that "the built-in cronjob options in my free domain" is not cron and you've not indicated which of these operations are runnning from a shell and which are over the web. Votong to close.

Comment: @Cybrus: the extension of the file nor its content have got nothing to do with the problem. (I also suspect that there may be caching involved). write some code to embed the right URL, don't change the image file.

Comment: Then look into `symlink`ing. There's easier ways to handle what you want to do.

Comment: @symcbean this is how the cron-job panel [looks like](http://image.prntscr.com/image/3c7c418aa2eb4823862848e5b89bdb93.png). I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Anyhow, @Blake, wrong solution is not the problem presented.. The cron-job can't run for some reason and times out while when i access it - it works. So what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your cron jobs runs from a different directory.

Depending on you PHP version you can either add a new line after `<?php`:

`chdir(__DIR__);`

or for older versions:

`chdir(dirname(__FILE__));`

This will change nothing when running from the webserver, but will make sure your cron job runs from the right directory.

However: some webservers have a security feature that does not allow you to freely change the directory when running on the server. In that case you will get an error that you can prevent by changing the directory only when running on the command-line:

```
   if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
     chdir(__DIR__);
   }
```

Comment: Don't know if i didn't use it correctly, but it did not work.  
New line of code i wrote is: `chdir("/public_html");`
FTP Hierarchy: [Screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/790ac5bb419c4a219c881a2c6bde0971.png)

Comment: Use the exact line mentioned by @Matijs. It should then work on your hosting

Comment: /public_html is very definitively wrong. /home/a3638901/public_html would work on this server. However, the code above is both shorter and works for every deployment so you should use that code.

Comment: @Matijs, Okay. I have done that now i have the following [error](http://prntscr.com/cnb9tn)

Comment: Actually that is a different problem, but I added the solution to the answer.

Comment: @Matijs, Okay, great! The script works now when accessing it directly.  
Will the cron-job command: `php -f /home/a3638901/public_html/imagechange.php` be valid now?

Comment: Try it first from the command line. It that works, cron should not be a problem either.